# Can someone tell me why this method is going into an infinite loop?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

So it seems this method is going into an infinite loop if the if(printLibraryNumber.equals(borrowersArray[index].getLibraryNumber() statement is true, and I have no idea why.

```
public boolean printBorrower(String printLibraryNumber)
{
   int index = 0;
   boolean isPrinted = false;
   while(index < currentIndex)
   {
       if(printLibraryNumber.equals(borrowersArray[index].getLibraryNumber()))
       {
           borrowersArray[index].printBorrowerDetails();
           isPrinted = true;
       }
       else
       {
           index++;
           isPrinted = false;
       }
   }

   if(isPrinted == false)
   {
       System.out.println("Borrower with library number " + printLibraryNumber + " not found.");
    }

   return isPrinted;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the

```
if(printLibraryNumber.equals(borrowersArray[index].getLibraryNumber()))
```

statement is always `true`, the **if** code block will be executed, & the **else** block will not. And since you don't alter the `index` variable in the **if** block, you get into an **infinite loop** because it's the `index` variable that shall decide when to **stop it**.

You need to increment the `index` variable **outside** of any condition code block :

```
while(index < currentIndex)
{
    if(printLibraryNumber.equals(borrowersArray[index].getLibraryNumber()))
    {
         borrowersArray[index].printBorrowerDetails();
         isPrinted = true;
    }
    else
    {
         isPrinted = false;
    }

    index++; // increment here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, when `if(printLibraryNumber.equals(borrowersArray[index].getLibraryNumber()))` is `true` you do not change the `index`. Thus, it tests the same index on the next loop iteration. Where it's true. Thus an infinite loop. I think you wanted something like,

```
int index = 0;
while (index < currentIndex) {
    if (printLibraryNumber.equals(borrowersArray[index].getLibraryNumber())) {
        borrowersArray[index].printBorrowerDetails();
        return true;
    }
    index++;
}
System.out.printf("Borrower with library number %s not found.%n", printLibraryNumber);
return false;
```

Comment: So now I've got this;

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/516ac35d783e947a5abb

But it still gives an infinite loop?

Comment: You still **aren't** changing `index` when the condition is **true**.

Answer (score 0):

This is your loop condition:

```
while(index < currentIndex)
```

If this is true:

```
printLibraryNumber.equals(borrowersArray[index].getLibraryNumber())
```

Then you do this:

```
borrowersArray[index].printBorrowerDetails();
isPrinted = true;
```

Which means neither `index` nor `currentIndex` is modified.  So your loop condition is still true.  And it will continue to be true.

In order to exit a loop either the loop condition needs to be false at some point or you need to use a `return` or `break` statement.  (Or, well, throw an exception or in some way cause the system to fail.  But that would be a bit drastic.)

Answer (score 0):

Right after:

```
isPrinted = true;
```

Add in

```
return isPrinted;
```

That should do it I think. Good luck!